# How to use group by in django on many files

Tags: django, sql-order-by

I hava a model which hava three field: email, phone, postal code. If there is a field of the same, we just take the first record.
For example:

```
field     email         phone    postal_code
record1   a@gmail.com   123      12
record2   b@gmail.com   321      12
record3   c@gmail.com   123      21
```

For postal_code: we can get the record1 and record3, then throught phone(is 123), the result is record1. last I can get the record1.

Answer (score 0):

Let's supose your model name is `Record`, you can do like:

```
Record.objects.all()  # This return all record objects

Record.objects.all().order_by('phone')  # Ascendent order by
Record.objects.all().order_by('-phone')  # Descendent order by

Record.objects.filter(phone=123)  # This should return record1 and record3

# This should return record1 and record3 ordered by postal_code ascendent
Record.objects.filter(phone=123).order_by('postal_code')  

# This should return record1 and record3 ordered by postal_code descendent
Record.objects.filter(phone=123).order_by('-postal_code')  

# This return a list of tuples [('record1', 12), ...]
Record.objects.filter(postal_code=12).values_list('name','postal_code')

# This return a list of dictionaries [{'name':'record1', 'postal_code':12}, ...]
Record.objects.filter(postal_code=12).values('name','postal_code)
```

Comment: It's not a solution I need,  But thanks a lot.
And I want to know can I use the `group by ` as same as SQL:
`select * from (select * from Record group by postal_code) as tmp_postal_code group by phone`.

Comment: @sweetpotato You want to get the Records grouped by postal_code, and then from that get the query grouped by phone ? What do you expect to get with Django ? A dict like `{'phone':123, 'postal_code':12, count: 1 }` ?